# boolean retrieval php

Tags: php, matrix, search-engine, boolean, information-retrieval

I'm using to php to make a simple search engine that is base on the boolean retrieval 
I have predefined documents 
for example: 
- doc0: my name is caesar 
- doc1: caesar is character...
-doc2.....

I've constructed the term-document matrix as follows : [image]

so for example "my" exists in the first documents , but not in the second and "caesar" is in the both documents 
when I do a search for a single term i get the boolean values of the term thus if I type "name" in the search engine i'll get 1 0 .

**my problem is that I want to search for mor than one term e.g: "caesar character"**
I want to make a boolean and between their boolean values thus the result of the search will be  0 1 as 1 1 & 0 1 = 01
 **So I need  php function that make me the search for more than one word using the mentioned method**

**This is the code**
$query = $_REQUEST['keyword'];
$stoplists = array("i",".","a"," ");
$words=array();
$wordsdoc=array();
$matrix=array();
$docs = array ("my name is caesar","caesar is a character");
$k=0;

```
//looping the docs array
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($docs);$i++)
{
    //splitting doc[i] on " " (space)
    $words_temp=explode(" ",$docs[$i]);

   //looping the splitted words
   for ($j=0;$j<sizeof($words_temp);$j++)
   {
        //checking if the word is not in stop dictionnary and does not already added in words array
        if (!in_array($words_temp[$j],$stoplists) && !in_array($words_temp[$j],$words))
        {
            //adding word to words array
            $words[$k]=$words_temp[$j];
            //incrementing counter
            $k++;       
        }

    }
    //print_r($words[1]);
}

echo "<b>Words:</b> ";
for ($j=0;$j<sizeof($words);$j++)
{
    echo $words[$j]." ";
}

echo "<br><br>";

//looping the docs array
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($docs);$i++)
{
    //splitting doc[i] on " " (space)
    $words_temp=explode(" ",$docs[$i]);
    //initialize counter
    $l=0;

    //looping the splitted words
    for ($j=0;$j<sizeof($words_temp);$j++)
    {
        //checking if the word is not in stop dictionnary
        if (!in_array($words_temp[$j],$stoplists) )
        {
            //adding word to 2d array
            $wordsdoc[$i][$l]=$words_temp[$j];
            //incrementing counter
            $l++;       
        }

    }
}

echo "<b><u>Docs:</u></b><br>";
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($wordsdoc);$i++)
{
    echo "doc".$i.": ";
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($wordsdoc[$i]);$j++)
    {
        echo $wordsdoc[$i][$j]." ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "<br>";

echo "<b>Res Matrix First Col:</b><br>";
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($words);$i++)
{
    $matrix[$i][0]=$words[$i];
    echo $matrix[$i][0]."<br>";
}

$i1=0;
$i2=0;

foreach($wordsdoc as $items)
{
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($words);$i++)
        {   
            if(in_array($matrix[$i][0],$items))
                $matrix[$i][$i1+1] = 1;
            else
                $matrix[$i][$i1+1] =0;
        }
    $i1++;
}

echo "<table border=1><br>";
echo "<tr><td></td>";

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($docs);$i++)
{
    echo "<td>doc".($i+1)."</td>";
}
echo "</tr><br>";

foreach($matrix as $items)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        echo "<td>".$item."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr><br>";
}
echo "</table><br>";
```

*I'm sorry for posting such a long question, but I really need help :S *
thank You guys in advance :)

Comment: Without providing more info about how you are implementing the `matrix` and how you query it, @Vidor's is the only possible advise.

Comment: We can treat your `search($word)` function as a *black box*; then tally all result arrays into an overall one. I have suggested a method below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function search($word) {
  ... code to query the matrix ...
  return $result_array;
}
```

use with multiple words

```
$search_terms = array('my', 'caesar');
$overall_result = array(true, true);
foreach($search_terms as $st) {
  $this_result = search($st);
  $overal_index = 0;
  foreach($this_result as $b) {
    $overall_result[$overal_index] = $b && $overall_result[$overal_index];
    $overal_index++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try to explode the search query and do the search for each part of the array and then merge the results as you like

Comment: thats is right but suppose i have a search($word) function that returns an array or boolean values, i explode the query and make the search foreach word but what is the way to stock them and do the boolean and between them ?